# Hide email address in mailto settings

Tags: c#, .net, email, mailto

I am creating some buttons that will allow my users to submit a bug report or a feature request. They do this by sending their information directly to a folder in my inbox.

Is there a way to hide my email address or 'mask it' so that they are not able to see exactly who it is going to?

Here is an example of my code:

```
  <ul id="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#" target="_top">Tool Bug Report</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Feature Request</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
```

Comment: Is javascript acceptable to do this?

Comment: A form would be more appropriate. Alternatively, you can create a new email address called bugs@...

Comment: No way to do exactly what you're asking, since their email client will show them the email address when the window pops up. You have to either set up a proxy email address, or write a form.

Comment: It is possible via COM dll assembly, that will run on client side.. refer to my answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not possible in mailto link. For that you will have to use forms only

Answer (score 0):

You can create an activeX dll component and call it onclick of a link via browser javascript.

The activeX dll must be programmed with the email address and the functionality to send the mail. Also, from browser, using javascript, you can pass parameters into the dll too..